# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

```
import Vue from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue"
import router from "./router"

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
})
```

ㄴ main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import { Login, SignUp } from "../components/index";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Login",
      component: Login,
    },
    {
      path: "/sign-up",
      name: "SignUp",
      component: SignUp,
    },
  ],
});
```

ㄴ router/index.js

> index.js?a18c:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of
> undefined
> at eval (index.js?a18c:5)
> at Module../src/router/index.js (app.js:1213)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:849)
> at fn (app.js:151)
> at eval (main.js:12)
> at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1201)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:849)
> at fn (app.js:151)
> at Object.1 (app.js:1226)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:849)

ㄴ error console message

Where is the problem? I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: Did you do npm install? and try log the Vue

Comment: I installed it with yarn and I also have vue.